How to reduce GCS A and B operations in a Spark Structured Streaming pipeline in Dataproc?
I'm running a data pipeline where a NiFi on-premise flow writes JSON files in streaming to a GCS bucket. I have 5 tables, each with their own path, generating around 140k objects per day. The bucket has a lifecycle policy to delete objects older than 1 day.
The pipeline consists of three main stages, each using Spark Structured Streaming (SSS) on separate Dataproc clusters (1 master and 2 n2-standard-4 workers per cluster). Each stream is configured with a processingTime of 3 minutes.

First stage: Reads the raw JSON data from GCS, applies basic cleansing rules, and writes the results back to GCS in Delta Lake format (insert-only) for the 5 tables.

Second stage: Reads from the trusted Delta Lake tables and performs a series of transformations and aggregations, mapping fields from the 5 tables to 3 target staging tables.

Third stage: Reads the Change Data Feed (CDF) from the staging tables, performs a CDC, applies some final transformations and aggregations, and writes the refined gold data in Delta format to a final layer, which is exposed to users through external tables in BigQuery.


Each of the 3 jobs runs continuously with Spark Structured Streaming, processing data every 3 minutes.
Issue:
After checking the billing in GCP, I noticed that each job is generating roughly 140,000 A-type operations and 210,000 B-type operations per hour in GCS. This translates to approximately $500/month solely for GCS operations.
I've already tried tweaking the Spark-GCS connector configurations, but it hasn't significantly reduced the number of operations. In some cases, the number of operations even increased. Here are the configurations I've tested:
fs.gs.list.max.items.per.call: "30000"
fs.gs.performance.cache.enable: "true"
fs.gs.performance.cache.max.entry.age: "150s"
fs.gs.inputstream.min.range.request.size: "32m"
fs.gs.max.requests.per.batch: "200"
fs.gs.outputstream.upload.chunk.size: "64m"
fs.gs.glob.algorithm: "FLAT"
fs.gs.batch.thread: "10"

Despite these changes, the number of operations remains high.
Dataproc/Spark setup:

Dataproc image: 2.2-debian12
Apache Spark: 3.5.1
Delta Lake: 3.2.0
Spark Configurations:
spark.jars.packages: "io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.2.0"
spark.sql.extensions: "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension"
spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog: "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled: "true"
spark.databricks.delta.allowArbitraryProperties.enabled: "true"
spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.enableChangeDataFeed: "false"
spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.logRetentionDuration: "7 days"
spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.deletedFileRetentionDuration: "7 days"
spark.databricks.delta.properties.defaults.randomizeFilePrefixes: "true"
spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled: "false"
spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled: "true"
spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrites.enabled: "true"
spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.binSize: "134217728"
spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.maxShufflePartitions: "1000"
spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.numShuffleBlocks: "30000000"
spark.databricks.delta.optimize.repartition.enabled: "true"
spark.databricks.delta.vacuum.parallelDelete.enabled: "true"
spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown: "true"
spark.executor.heartbeatInterval: '100000'
spark.network.timeout: '300'
spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields: '150'
spark.sql.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite: "LEGACY"
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions: '200'
spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles: 'true'
spark.sql.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite: "CORRECTED"
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold: '-1'
spark.sql.adaptive.enabled: 'false'



Question:
What are the best practices or further optimizations I can apply to the Spark-GCS connector or my overall Spark Structured Streaming setup to reduce the number of GCS A and B operations, especially considering the lifecycle policy and the large number of files? Any insights on configurations or architectural changes to minimize GCS operation costs would be greatly appreciated.
